# Write JSON to DOC file in PHP

Tags: php, json, cakephp-2.0

I have a situation where a webserver posts a JSON array which includes some parameters as well as a document data within it. I get the data, content-type and filename. I convert this JSON into an associative array so that I can work with it. An example of the converted associative array is given below.

```
[dealer] => Array
  (
    [fullName] => John Doe
    [email] => john@gmail.com
    [resume] => Array
  (
  [file] => Array
  (
    [data] => 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
    [fileName] => John_resume.docx
    [contentType] => application/octet-stream
  )
)
```

I am trying to write this to the file system and am able to do so but the file is written as a text file and not as a binary file. The code I have in place to do this is also provided below.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$document = json_decode($json, true, 32, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

$resumeFileData = $document['resume']['file']['data'];
$filePath = $folderPath . DS . $document['resume']['file']['fileName'];
$resumeFile = new File($filePath, true);
$resumeFile->write($resumeFileData);
$resumeFile->close();
```

What am I doing incorrectly? I am using CakePHP 2.5.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to create a docx document ? A word file, using only cakephp ?

Comment: what do you mean it's not written as a binary file. what file format are you expecting?

Comment: I dont want to create a 'new' docx document. I am receiving a docx document as a json stream and I just need to store that stream back into a readable file structure. Currently when I save it and then reopen it, all I see is the same garbled string that I shared in the example - leading me to believe that the mime-type or some header information is missing

Comment: where is $resumeFileData being set?

Comment: Edited to include the code where resumeFileData is being set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
$resumeFileData = base64_decode($document['resume']['file']['data']);
```

Comment: Thanks - i also added `base64_decode(chunk_split($document['resume']['file']['data']));` to handle large files

Comment: I don't think you want to do that, that's usually used when you encode, not decode.

Comment: that actually might mess up the file as it'll add a /r/n by default every 76 characters.